# Rails showing records from multiple models and tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sorry ahead of time for asking a simple question. Been searching for a few hours and haven't been able to fix the problem yet.

I'm defining 2 variables within the Users Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @record = Record.joins(:user).where(:user_id => 2).select('records.id, records.wins')
  end
 end
```

In my .html.erb file, I have want to display the wins for that user. The code looks as follows:

```
 <%= @user.name %>
 <%= @record.wins %>
```

The name of the user appears with no issues, but for the wins I get a "NoMethodError in Users#shows. undefined method `wins' for #

Table schema looks as follows:

```
 create_table "records", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
t.integer "wins"
t.bigint "user_id"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_records_on_user_id"
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
t.string "name"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Perhaps you should add the full stack trace to your question with the full error. `@record` appears not to an instance of Record. Also, your associations *might* help.

Answer (score 0):

If your association look like `User` `has_many` `Record`

then for user

```
#=> controller
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

in the view

```
<%= @user.name %>
#=> wins for this user
<% @user.records.each do |user_record| %>
    <% user_record.wins %>
<% end %>
```

you don't need this line in the controller

```
@record = Record.joins(:user).where(:user_id => 2).select('records.id, records.wins')
```